# Trying to display images using JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display different plane images on a canvas. I have a JSON file that includes the name of cities in an array:

```json
{
    "cities": [{
        "city": "St. John",
        "xCoor": 931,
        "yCoor": 349
    }, {
        "city": "Halifax",
        "xCoor": 844,
        "yCoor": 424
    }, {
        "city": "Charlottetown",
        "xCoor": 838,
        "yCoor": 407
    }, {
        "city": "Fredericton",
        "xCoor": 800,
        "yCoor": 422
    }, {
        "city": "Quebec",
        "xCoor": 734,
        "yCoor": 427
    }, {
        "city": "Ottawa",
        "xCoor": 685,
        "yCoor": 459
    }, {
        "city": "Toronto",
        "xCoor": 655,
        "yCoor": 483
    }, {
        "city": "Winnipeg",
        "xCoor": 420,
        "yCoor": 430
    }, {
        "city": "Regina",
        "xCoor": 336,
        "yCoor": 417
    }, {
        "city": "Edmonton",
        "xCoor": 250,
        "yCoor": 364
    }, {
        "city": "Victoria",
        "xCoor": 111,
        "yCoor": 398
    }, {
        "city": "Whitehorse",
        "xCoor": 115,
        "yCoor": 235
    }, {
        "city": "Yellowknife",
        "xCoor": 285,
        "yCoor": 271
    }, {
        "city": "Iqaluit",
        "xCoor": 645,
        "yCoor": 243
    }]
}
```

Now, I want to display images on a canvas in a random position on the canvas using random plane images corresponding to the name of the cities, and I'm not sure if I am doing it properly.

Here is how I got the JsonData:

```js
function getJsonData() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            schedule = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "capitals.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

And the code I used to try and display the images on the canvas:

```js
function drawPlanes() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cityNames = schedule["cities"];
    var randomCity = cityNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * cityNames.length)];

    ctx.drawImage(findImage(randomCity), 0, 0);
    console.log(randomCity);
}


function findImage(cityNames) {
    if (cityNames == "Iqaluit" || cityNames == "Whitehorse" || cityNames == "Yellowknife") {
        return "img/plane.jpg";
    }

    if (cityNames == "Halifax" || cityNames == "Charlottetown" || cityNames == "Winnipeg" ||
        cityNames == "Regina" || cityNames == "Edmonton" ||
        cityNames == "Victoria" || cityNames == "Toronto" || cityNames == "St.John") {

        return "img/" + cityNames.toLowerCase + ".jpg";
    }

    if (cityNames == "Fredericton" || cityNames == "Ottawa" || cityNames == "Quebec") {
        return "img/" + cityNames.toLowerCase + ".png";
    }
}
```

Any type of clarification on how to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you control that json file?

Comment: first mistake: `*.toLowerCase` should be `*.toLowerCase()` because you need to execute the function

Comment: @ChrisStrickland no I'm not supposed to alter it if thats what you mean

Comment: @Sysix you are right rookie mistake

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  It would be a lot cleaner to add the image as a property of the json object for each city.  Then you could avoid all that boolean mishmash, plus having to maintain that anytime your cities or images change.  But if you can't, you can't.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland well right now Im getting `canvas.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':` but I know the reason why I'm getting just don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete error you are getting is probably this one:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

The problem here is that [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) requires an Image object as its first parameter.

Your `findImage` function currently returns the image path.

You could alter your function like this:

```js
function drawPlanes() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const cityNames = schedule["cities"];
    const randomCity = cityNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * cityNames.length)];
    console.log(randomCity);

    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    };
    image.src = findImage(randomCity);
}
```

Comment: I understand, is there an extra step that I need to do before using `findImage()` because I am not sure how to do it

Comment: @Joe you need to create an Image object using the image path. I updated my answer with a code snippet I think should work.

Comment: I am getting a new error now `undefined:1 GET http://localhost/FlightSimulator-TheodoreTsimiklis/Simulator-TheodoreTsimiklis/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Looks like `findImage` does not return the proper image file path. You will have to set a breakpoint and debug your code to find the problem. It's hard to tell just by looking at the code. Maybe the loading of the JSON already fails.